# Trigger involving two tables SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

CONTRACTS (player, team)

MATCHES (player, team, match)

team is a NUMBER(1) from 0 to 9.

Attribute team in MATCHES have to be the same of this player in contracts or 1 less or 1 more. (In matches, the same player could appear more than one time).

I have to check with a trigger if all the players in MATCHES fulfill the condition that I stated previously

I have tried that, but not found:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER trigA
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF team on matches
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE error EXCEPTION;
  BEGIN
  IF (:NEW.team!=contracts.team OR :NEW.team!=contracts.team +1 OR :NEW.team!=contracts.team -1) AND (:NEW.player) = contracts.player
  THEN error;
  END IF;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN error THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Team');
  END;
/
```

Comment: Nothing. It's my first trigger that involves two tables and I dont know what can I do.

Comment: Start with the shell of a trigger definition - the event, timing, scope and context - and post it in your question. Knowing that will make the next part easier.

Comment: Also, you've tagged this for both "Oracle" and "MySQL." Are you using both products, or should you drop one of the tags?

Comment: Sorry, I am using only oracle. I know what a trigger makes because I made one but that trigger only involved one table..

Comment: No problem; I know both, although my Oracle is a bit rusty. Start with a shell definition, and then we'll fill in the logic.

Comment: I have just edited my post with a try..

Comment: A trigger is **always** related to a single table. You can't create a trigger for two tables. It also doesn't make sense: an `insert` or `update` statement always affects a single table anyway. You need to write one trigger for each table.

Comment: But I need to link both triggers.. How can I do this?

Comment: Good start. Now here's two hints: a trigger is procedural, so you can do pretty much anything you can in a stored procedure, and while a row trigger can't query the table it's attached to, it can query any other table.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance.. but I dont know what could I do... Its my second trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your trigger you need to query the CONTRACTS table within your trigger, looking for CONTRACTS rows which satisfy the condition you've got. If you find at least one everything is fine. If you don't you need to raise an error.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MATCHES_BIU_TEAM
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF team on matches
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  nContract_count  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO nContract_count
    FROM CONTRACTS c
    WHERE c.PLAYER = :NEW.PLAYER AND
          c.TEAM BETWEEN :NEW.TEAM - 1
                     AND :NEW.TEAM + 1;

  IF nContract_count = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(...);
  END IF;
END MATCHES_BIU_TEAM;
```

Go look up how to use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` to raise an exception which the calling program can capture. This is important because if an exception *does* occur you don't want to just have it disappear in an EXCEPTION handler in a trigger - it needs to be raised so that the calling application code can handle it.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for you comment!!
I have been looking online and I have concluded write:

"(...)  IF nContract_count = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'ERROR');   (...)"

But I have tested if it works in a bad case and not. Appears 'ERROR' but then gives me another error in the next line: "c.TEAM BETWEEN :NEW.TEAM - 1"

PD: In valid cases it works

Comment: @Dan: it appears that's exactly the error you should be getting. You've inserted a new row into MATCHES with PLAYER='Peter', TEAM=1, and MATCH=41. You haven't included the data from CONTRACTS but I'm guessing that CONTRACTS_AUX shows the same information. If so, there are values in CONTRACTS for PLAYER='Peter' and TEAM=5. When the trigger fires it looks for data in CONTRACTS for PLAYER='Peter' and TEAM between 0 and 2, and finds that there is nothing in CONTRACTS which matches, and thus returns 0 as the row count. The trigger sees that the row count is 0 and raises exception -20000.

Comment: Mmm, I thought the following errors shouldn't appear.. Thanks!

Comment: The ORA-20000 is the one you issue. The following two (the ORA-06512 and ORA-04088) are issued by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MATCHES_BIU_TEAM
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF team on matches
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  matchTeam  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT c.team
    INTO matchTeam
    FROM CONTRACTS c
    WHERE c.player = :NEW.player;

  IF matchTeam < :NEW.team - 1 OR matchTeam > :NEW.team + 1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(...);
  END IF;
END MATCHES_BIU_TEAM;
```

This assumes a) that you want to compare the *value* of `contracts.team` with the *value* of `matches.team` (Bob Jarvis' answer compares the *number of records* in `contracts` to the value of `matches.team`), and b) that there is exactly one record in `contracts` for each player.

Comment: Thanks for you comment!! But trigger gives me execution problems when I try insert a row invalid.. Dont show me only my RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
I understand your trigger, and Bob Jarvis trigger too, but I dont know why not work

Comment: When you write RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR the insertion is not done?

Comment: Correct. Raising the error causes the trigger to fail, which in turn causes the triggering statement to fail. See [Triggers for Complex Constraint Checking](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#CIHDDGGD) in the [Oracle Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm).